# ExactTarget (Marketing Cloud) Get Message Rest API call returning 500

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, gack

I am attempting to retrieve all messages from our ExactTarget instance for an ETL. I am following the [documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/push/retrieveAllPushMessages.html) from ExactTarget's code@ site. However the calls are returning a 500 Internal Server Error. Here is my request in Ruby:

```
  begin
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/message', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' + access_token}, :timeout => 600, :open_timeout => 600)
  rescue => e
    e.response
  end
```

This is the 500 error response:

```
{
  "documentation"=>"https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/500",
  "errorcode"=>0,
  "message"=>"Internal Server Error"
}
```

*Note: the documentation link is dead.*

The credentials used are good and using foo credentials results in a *401 Unauthorized* response as expected. Is there a better way to extract all data from ExactTarget for an ETL system? Is it possible to get useful error codes from ExactTarget?

Comment: What happens when you try to hit the endpoint in a chrome extension like Postman?

Comment: @DrewSimmons, same response. Thanks for introducing me to that chrome extension though :)

Comment: I'm getting 200 OK on that endpoint in Postman.  So we know it's not Ruby.  It's not your token because it'd be a different error message.  Can you hit some other Marketing Cloud endpoint and get 200?

Comment: Yes, I get 200 when I GET /platform/v1/endpoints, /interaction/v1/rest, contacts/v1/schema, /hub/v1/campaigns, and /interaction/v1/interactions

Comment: In Admin, make sure the user account has roles and permissions for everything relating to Push.

Comment: In the Marketing Cloud, are you able to bring up MobilePush and access all functionality?

Comment: @DrewSimmons, I included Read, Send, & Write permissions for Push but the problem was the same. Where would I find MobilePush in Marketing Cloud? Thanks mate!

Comment: In the app bar (Email, Mobile, Social, Ads, Web, etc).  Some or all may be in your account according to your account setup.  Hovering over one will drop down a menu of apps.  Hovering over Mobile will show a menu with MobileConnect and MobilePush.  If you don't have those it may be the reason for 500 on the 'push' endpoint.

Comment: I don't have Mobile in my menu. My intention is to extract all emails sent for an ETL. Should I be using a different REST endpoint?

Comment: You may have to use the SOAP API, which is more robust for email: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an email ETL, you may have to use the SOAP API, which is more robust for email. Check out [this article](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/).